# How to select data from table with parameter

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Trying to get all the data in the row with the specified name string. Im getting a syntax error right now. `myConn` is declared in the constructor and name is a varchar in the database named organization. My error code is "Can not issue executeUpdate() or executeLargeUpdate() for SELECTs"

```
    public void getOrgByName(String name){

    try {
        st = myConn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM organization WHERE name =  ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, name);
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Cannot get org name" + e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re performing a select query so you’ll need to use `executeQuery` i.e

Replace this:

```
preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

With this:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
```